# Where to start when making a keyboard Macro program

Tags: macros, keyboard

*So here's the situation (the post premise)-*

Skill wise I’m just out of computer science college, and have been given the basic tools in understanding about software development. This means that I know enough to make a phone directory program that loads a file, or a simple calculator. I'm also sort of familiar with the .net framework, as VB.net was used in all out end of year projects.

What I’m basically saying, is that, without humiliating myself, is that I know very little.

However, I was struck with a necessity - I was playing a game, and I need a keyboard Macro. My keyboard comes with one, but it is near useless, and as software its of poor quality (it’s a corsair keyboard as well).

*Well in short, I think I found myself a project.*

So, what I want to create, is a simple Macro program that allows the user to use "visually scripting" for ease of use. In other words, its purely GUI, and it’s made in a way that people that know nothing about scripting, can use it.

The program is for keyboard only (don't want to do mouse just yet), and it does not need a record function, (even if I feel that, that is the easiest function to make from what I learned from .net. I'll add it later if I feel the need).

*So what I need to ask is -*

Given what I have expressed above, can I ask where I would need to start with this? As mentioned I know about some aspects, limited to VB.net and I’m also familiar with some JavaScript, and C++.

Points I’m shaky or clueless on, are;

- How to get it to send out the event as if a key has been pressed, as
  if the hardware was the one pressing it. This could also be interpreted as a question of "what does a Macro program do, code wise?". I’m aware of its function, but how does it do that function?
- Some "from the ground up" UI building that's outside windows forms (I
  can research it, but I would like to know, with context to the
  project, what should I research first?)

In short, I just need pointers in the right direction as I know I’m lacking, and hoping I’m not biting off more than I can chew. It seemed like a good project to get me coding something I will use, which is what I have been lacking since ending college.